# Issues with entitlements and iCloud

Tags: ios, cocoa, xcode4.2, icloud, entitlements

I try to configure iCloud for my app. I enabled iCloud for my iPhone App, generated a new provisioning developer profile.
Of course I use the new profile in Xcode (instead of the wildcard one), I enable entitlements but still I have the following error when I try to synchronize with iCloud :

> NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.company.app has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement

I really don't understand what's going on and I'm starting to losing my mind.
The weird thing is that it's perfectly working for my iPad app (I did the same steps).

Comment: Is the bundle id of your application really `com.company.app` (i.e. generic) or is it set to something more specific?

Comment: I try to use the same iCloud container id for both application.
But no matter what I specify in the entitlement file, it uses the bundle of the App... Apple says we can do that but the entitlements settings seems to be attached in the provisioning profile.

Comment: While giving support for iCloud, Should we enable iCloud in existing working app ID or should we create new app ID with iCloud enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need a development provisioning profile for the Mac app as well and it can not be the same as the iOS one. You need to create an App ID (make sure it is exactly the same as your bundle ID in the app), turn on iCloud for that ID. Create a development provisioning profile and install the profile on the machine (just double click it) and drag it over to Xcode. Then use that profile to sign the app. 
If you still don't have permission to use iCloud (the message teling you this may not go to Xcode it may stay hidden in Console.app) delete your container (`~/Library/Containers/`) and try again.

Comment: While giving support for iCloud, Should we enable iCloud in existing working app ID or should we create new app ID with iCloud enabled?

Comment: If you have an app ID for the app you are working on you should add an iCloud container for it, and enable it in for the ID. After that you can create a provisioning profile.

Comment: I did it exactly. But after clicking 'Fix Issue' button under XCode iCloud capability, newly created provisioning profile becomes invalid in developer member center, everytime.